# javascript doesn't work all the time in IE

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

Using spring form tags in jsp.

Following is my script,which i am using for pagination :

```
function getNextPage(){
var next = document.getElementById('nextPageID');
next.checked=true;
var buttonName = document.getElementById('refreshbuttonID');
buttonName.click();
}
```

when user clicks `Next` in view (using jsp), `onclick` event I am calling the `getNextPage();`

```
<button type="submit" onclick="getNextPage();">Next</button>
```

and I set hidden check-box to true

```
<td>
     <form:checkbox id="nextPageID" path="nextPage"/>  
     <input type="hidden" value="1" name="_nextPage"/>
</td>
```

and then calling the method in controller to get next results and show on page.

everything works fines in chrome and firefox, when it comes IE, some times it does and sometimes doesn't. and page keeps refreshing with old data..It works all the time in debug mode (even in IE)

`It is not hitting the javascript in IE on some occassions`. is there something I am missing in function or something different to do in IE? Any suggestions!

Comment: Is that really all your code? Also I think some debugging is in order.

Comment: what else I can show here?

Comment: it is not hitting the `javascript` on `onclick` event in IE

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: What the heck is `<form:checkbox />`?

Comment: `<form:checkbox />` spring form tag for checkbox

Comment: @user1609085 added relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess based on the limited information given: change your button to use `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getNextPage();">Next</button>
```

...because if you have a submit button in a form and you don't cancel the default behaviour (which your code doesn't) it will try to submit the form in addition to whatever your code is doing.